# plutus-playground-server: user error (Error evaluating simulation: JsonDecodingError

Tags: plutus, plutus-pioneer-program, plutus-playground

I'm following the first lecture in the plutus pioneer program but I cannot set up the local environment. The error happens when running `npm start` on a nix-shell after initializing the playground server.

```
The following purescript packages are needed by the generated code:

  - plutus-playground-client
  - purescript-either
  - purescript-foreign-generic
  - purescript-maybe
  - purescript-ordered-collections
  - purescript-profunctor-lenses
  - web-common

Successfully created your PureScript modules!
plutus-playground-server: user error (Error evaluating simulation: JsonDecodingError {expected = "EvaluationResult", decodingError = "Error in $: not enough input", input = ""})
```

I'm using windows 10 with WSL2

Comment: I would recommend opening an issue on the plutus issue tracker for this kind of case: https://github.com/input-output-hk/plutus/issues

Comment: Might be this? "If you're using Windows and WSL, make sure the plutus repo clone is located in the WSL filesystem" (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68276780/plutus-playground-client-cannot-run)

Comment: No, it is located in the WSL filesystem. I'm planning to switch to ubuntu

Comment: Did you ever find the solution? I have the same issue...masOS i7 Monterey.

Answer (score -1):

I recommend installing Virtual Box and using NixOS or just installing NixOS on a flash drive.

[Here](https://nixos.org/nixos/manual/index.html#ch-installation) is an installation guide.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but this is not really a solution to the problem

Comment: Are you running in a Nix shell?

Comment: Yes, It is activated